# Running a shell script interactively from a Java class in Linux machine

Tags: java, shell

I have a simple shell script which prints "Hello world", asks for a number from user and prints that number.
I am trying to run this script from a Java class in linux machine using runtime and process. 
However, when I run this Java class in linux machine from commandline using java command, it prints the first 2 lines and hangs at the point of taking input from user. I am not able to pass any input to the script.

Kindly let know how I can run the script interactively via java. Below is my script and java class file:

sample.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello world"
echo "Enter any number"
read response
echo "The number you entered is: $response"
```

ExecuteScript.java

```
package com.scripting;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class ExecuteScript {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Java program ran!!");
        String[] cmdScript = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "/root/sample.sh"};
        Process procScript = null;

        try {

            procScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream ip = procScript.getInputStream();
        OutputStream op = procScript.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(ip));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(op));
        BufferedReader consoleReader =  
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            while(reader.readLine() != null) {

                    if(!reader.ready()) {
                        String input = consoleReader.readLine();
                        writer.write(input);
                        writer.flush();
                    }else {
                        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
                    }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can possibly make this script parameter driven. And when you invoke the script, rather than taking an input from the user in script. Take it as part of your java program and run the script along with this parameter.

Comment: Hmm... But my problem is that I can't do it like this way because the script mentioned here is a sample shell script. The actual script I want to call is a long shell script which takes many inputs including password of root account and I cant send these as parameters to my script while running it.